# Change add to cart text including some jQuery code in single product pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the following jQuery script to every product page, before the footer, in order to change the text of woocommerce default add to cart button text. Where should I add it?

```
 <script>
    $(".wpb_wrapper, p").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace('Add to cart', 'Add to my cart');
});
<script>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please have a look at [ask] to learn how to ask a good question and get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the add to cart text on product archives by product types:

Add the below code in your project: wp-content/themes/select your active theme/functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
global $product;

  $product_type = $product->product_type;

  switch ( $product_type ) {
    case 'external':
        return __( 'Buy product', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'grouped':
        return __( 'View products', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'simple':
        return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'variable':
        return __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    default:
        return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to functions.php

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'single_add_to_card_lable' );
function single_add_to_card_lable() {
        return __( 'Add to my cart', 'woocommerce' );
}
```